# Пример MVC и MVVC в Angular2+

Tags: javascript, angular2, frontend

Всем доброго времени суток, прочитал с десяток статей и так, и не понял чем же отличаются эти 2 шаблона и как их применять в Angular2+. Сам шаблон это View, а что такое класс компонента, то тут уже не понятно, в некоторых статьях класс называют ViewModel, а в некоторых controller, одни класс моделью называют, другие сервис, третьи интерфейс класса. Хочется внятного ответа, что к чему относится в MVVM, что к чему в MVC и как понять когда, что использовать.